# Process of making a chalitza

Tags: provenance, yibbum-chalitza-levirate

Although I've never actually witnessed a chalitza taking place, I understand there is a whole process involved. What is the earliest source for the process/procedure/ceremony that takes place today (keeping mind that there might be varying minhagim)?

(Inspired somewhat by [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22262/sources-for-pidyon-haben-ceremony) about the pidyon haben ceremony and it's source.)

Comment: I don't know much about chalitza, but in most of our complex rituals, various elements were added at various times, and various communities include or exclude various elements. If chalitza is anything like that, then "the exact ... that takes place today" is an ill-defined term, and there's unlikely to be a single source for the whole thing, other than a recent how-to guide.

Comment: http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0525.htm#7

Comment: http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=eh_x8295

Comment: @DoubleAA who is Mahari Margolios and where did he get it from?

Comment: @Yehoshua Don't know. You are trying to balance age with similarity to current practice. The Shulchan Aruch seems like a good compromise.

Comment: @DoubleAA My curiosity (as I stated) came from that of Pidyon HaBen (which the makor is in Gaonim as you know...) So this, which has no source in Mesectas Yevamos, I was curious to know where the whole seder and practice comes from.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rTGbcHSKIU8